# Query for getting sorted data using post meta field

Tags: wordpress

I need sorted events using postmeta field which have value of date in format of 18 May 2017.This is my code but i dont get solution for sorting.

```
$args = array
(
'posts_per_page' => -1, 
'post_type' => 'movies', 
'meta_key' => 'event_release', 
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the meta type:

```
$args = array
(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'movies', 
    'meta_key' => 'event_release',
    'meta_type' => 'DATE', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: Hello inarilo i appreciate your reply but it won't work.

Comment: what type is your date field? if it's a string it won't sort correctly